# Scoped and scope in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can somebody explain what this method does and what I can pass to it?

```
scoped(options = nil)
Returns an anonymous scope.
```

And also what the scope method does? I don't understand after reading the documentation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In ActiveRecord, all query building methods (like `where`, `order`, `joins`, `limit` and so forth) return a so called *scope*. Only when you call a kicker method like `all` or `first` the built-up query is executed and the results from the database are returned.

The `scoped` class method also returns a scope. The scope returned is by default empty meaning the result set would not be restricted in any way meaning all records would be returned if the query was executed.
You can use it to provide an "empty" alternative like in the *query_by_date* example by MurifoX.
Or you can use it to combine multiple conditions into one method call, like for example:

```
Model.scoped(:conditions => 'id < 100', :limit => 10, :order => 'title ASC')

# which would be equivalent to
Model.where('id < 100').limit(10).order('title ASC')
```

The `scope` class method allows you to define a class method that also returns a scope, like for example:

```
class Model
  scope :colored, lambda {|col|
    where(:color => col)
  }
end
```

which can be used like this:

```
Model.colored
```

The nice thing with scopes is that you can combine them (almost) as you wish, so the following is absolutely possible:

```
Model.red.where('id < 100').order('title ASC').scoped(:limit => 10)
```

I also strongly suggest reading through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Thanks severin, it helped. How do I know what I can pass to .scoped? I see :conditions => etc.

Comment: You'll find a full list of all options here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find-label-Options

Comment: fyi as of Rails 4, `.scoped` is deprecated. `.all` instead replaces `.scoped` 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198963/with-rails-4-model-scoped-is-deprecated-but-model-all-cant-replace-it/

Comment: @JordanMichaelRushing you are right, but the question was explicitly about `.scoped` in Rails 3; so I'll just leave my answer as it is...

Answer (score 7):

I have used it in the past.When you make chained calls to the `ActiveRecord` query interface like this:

```
Model.where(:conditions).where(:more_conditions).where(:final_conditions)
```

Each one of them is already scoped, making the chain work without any problems. But let's say you have something like this:

```
Model.query_by_date(date).query_by_user(user).query_by_status(status)

scope :query_by_date, lambda { |date|
  case date
  when "today"
    where(:date => Date.today)
  when "tomorrow"
    where(:date => Date.tomorrow)
  else
    # Any value like '' or 0 or Date.whatever
  end
}
```

This would cause an error if the date param is not today or tomorrow. It would pick the last value and try to chain this query with the next one `query_by_user`, resulting in a `undefined method default_scoped? for ''`. But if you put a `scoped` method in the `else` condition, it would work without any flaws, because you are saying to activerecord that you pass through this method/named scope and didn't make any calls to `where/find/other activerecord methods`, but returned a scoped object, so you can continue chaining queries and stuff.
It would be this way in the end.

```
else
  scoped
end
```

Hope you understand this simple example.

Comment: Could you explain what it means to be "scoped"?

Comment: It's like "being" an ActiveRecord compliant. Encapsulated by all of ActiveRecords specifications.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand "scoped" other than that I understand what you mean...that is, I see it will fail otherwise. But I don't understand what the "scoped" can do and is.

Comment: So scoped means, "pretend the results I return were returned by a scope" or even "here is an empty scope"