# Model.order() passing nothing into rails order function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it legit to call something like User.order() if I have situation where I might have to pass some parameters but if they do not exist I need default order. Or is there some default call..

So for example

```
# if the order_by exists I need to sort by that otherwise I need to get default results
order = params[:order_by]
@results = User.order(order)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know which params will you receive, you can try to use following code:

```
@users = User.scoped # or any other default handler which returns ActiveRecord::Relation
@users = @users.where(name: params[:name]) if params[:name].present?
@users = @users.order(params[:order_by]) if params[:order_by].present?
```

Comment: Awesome! So User.scoped just returns default query? The docs on .scoped are not that clear.

Comment: It returns results of a query to specified table without any restrictions(of course when you fire it, just `User.scoped` code will not fetch anything, it will just return `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which you can modify according to your needs). You can read detailed explanation here: [Scoped and scope in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11902011)

Comment: That seems not to work with my code. Check out my other thread with code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207436/how-can-i-order-data-based-on-if-a-param-has-been-set-or-not

Comment: @CodeCrack you can't chain after `.all` or `.find` since these methods fire db query, in contrary to `.scoped`, which creates `AR::Relation`. And you have a typo `.scope` instead of `.scoped`. Leantraxxx gave you correct answer