# Chaining .order with .where - undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x007f85760dcb10>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I want to display all the data
I either try

```
@movies = Movie.find(:all)
or
@movies = Movie.scope #default call I think?
```

but then I also want to be able to .order based if there is a paramater set

```
 @movies = @movies.order(params[:sort_by]) if params[:sort_by]
```

I get the following errors

> undefined method `order' for #

Not sure how to fix this

EDIT: Update
here is the code. I can't seem to get the .order to work if .where is there as well. (IF I comment out .where then .order starts working

> 

```
  def index                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    @all_ratings = Movie.get_ratings                                                                                                                                                                              
    @movies = Movie.all                                                                                                                                                                                           
    sort_column = sort_by_column((params[:sort_by] || session[:sort_by]))                                                                                                                                         
    @movies = @movies.order(sort_column) if !sort_column.nil?                                                                                                                                                     

    ratings = (params[:ratings] || session[:ratings])                                                                                                                                                             
    if params[:commit] == "Refresh"                                                                                                                                                                               
      if !ratings.nil?                                                                                                                                                                                            
        @movies = @movies.where(rating: params[:ratings].keys)                                                                                                                                                    
      else                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        @movies = @movies.where(rating: @all_ratings)                                                                                                                                                             
      end                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      session[:ratings] = params[:ratings]                                                                                                                                                                        
    else                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      is_param_empty = (params[:ratings].nil?) ? true : false                                                                                                                                                     
      @movies = @movies.where(sort_by_ratings(ratings, is_param_empty))                                                                                                                                           
    end                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  end
```

> private
>
> ```
> def sort_by_column(sort_column)                                                                                                                                                                               
>   sort_by = Movie.column_names.include?(sort_column) ? sort_column : nil                                                                 
>
>   if !sort_by.nil?                                                                                                                                                                                            
>     params[:sort_by] = session[:sort_by] = sort_by                                                                                                                                                            
>   end                                                                                                                                                                                                         
>   return sort_by                                                                                                                                                                                              
> end                                                                                                                                                                                                           
>
> def sort_by_ratings(ratings, is_param_empty)                                                                                                                                                                  
>   if is_param_empty == true                                                                                                                                                                                   
>     params[:ratings] = session[:ratings]                                                                                                                                                                      
>     redirect_to movies_path(:ratings => params[:ratings], :commit => "Refresh",                                                                                                                               
>                             :sort_by => params[:sort_by])                                                                                                                                                     
>   else                                                                                                                                                                                                        
>     session[:ratings] = params[:ratings] = ratings                                                                                                                                                            
>     return ratings.keys                                                                                                                                                                                       
>   end                                                                                                                                                                                                         
> end
> ```

Getting undefined method `order' for # error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Rails 3, the ActiveRecord's `all` method returns an Array. So, if you try to execute `User.all.order(:first_name)` on Rails 3 you will get: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'order' for #<Array:0x007fd795de8a90>`
On Rails 4, the `all` method returns a chainable `ActiveRecord_Relation` instead. So, this code `User.all.order(:first_name)` will work on Rails 4.

If you are using Rails 3, you need to do `Movie.order` instead `Movie.all.order`

Comment: I was just seeing this as well.

Comment: But what if there is a possibility I might not use order.. so I wouldn't have the movies variable.. and then .where gets called... on movies..

Comment: If you are using Rails 3, you can have @movies = Movie.scoped at the top. Not Movie.scope, Movie.scoped with "d"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's going on up there, but if you want to order all Movie records, try something like this:

```
@movies = Movie.all
attr = params[:sort_by]
@movies = @movies.order(attr.to_sym => :asc) if attr
```